# Flutter Expanded widget error even if theres a Flex parent

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

Hi can you guys help me with this, I know that the `Expanded` widget requires a Flex parent. but for some reason, mine gives an error:

[image]

my code are:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(child: Text('BMI CALCULATOR')),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
                      child: Container(
              child: ReusableCard(colour: Color(0xFF141A3C)),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  //CUSTOM CONSTRUCTOR
  //the color from the Stateful Widget from above is passed in to the INPUT of ReusableCard({PASSED IN HERE}),

  ReusableCard({this.colour});
  Color colour;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        // height: 200.0,
        // width: 170.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

> Ive tried adding another Extended widget AS A CHILD of Column() but the error reappears

```
class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(child: Text('BMI CALCULATOR')),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              // <------ change this Container to a Row or Column
              children: <Widget>[
                ReusableCard(colour: Color(0xFF141A3C)),
                ReusableCard(colour: Color(0xFF141A3C)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ReusableCard(
              colour: Color(0xFF141A3C),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ReusableCard` (which returns an `Expanded` widget) is wrapped within a `Container` class. This is what's giving you the error. To fix this, you can simply change your `Container` class to a `Row` or `Column`:

```
class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(child: Text('BMI CALCULATOR')),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: Container( // <------ change this Container to a Row or Column
                   child: ReusableCard(colour: Color(0xFF141A3C)
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi this one fixed my problem but when I put another Expanded widget AS A CHILD of the body: Column(), the error reappears. Ill update my code